# http vs web socket memory usage per connection in spite of request body

Tags: sockets, http, websocket, connection

I need to benchmark how much memory used per connection in HTTP(request/response) vs web socket connection in the same condition(ex. request body).

How can I  theoretically or practically benchmark this scenario?

If any work already has done for this, please refer to me.

Answer (score 0):

The exact use of memory for websocket(not socket.io ) is: for 1 TCP connection it take 40MB, for 1000(1k) TCP connections it take 80 MB, for 10,000(10k) TCP connections it takes 210 MB.

Now if you use Socket.io then for 1000 TCP connections it will take 200MB, for 10,000(10k) TCP connection it take almost 2 GB. And most Importantly socket.io is around 3 times slower than pure websocket.

Conclusion:   So when you use pure websocket it becomes really efficient for both memory uses and data flowing speed.

Comment: What tools did you use for benchmarking?